# json4s scala.MatchError (of class scala.Tuple2)

Tags: scala, json4s

I have a custom class, that I want to convert to JSON but I am getting a weird error found here:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: (23,com.xxx.dts.dq.common.utils.DQOpsStoreProfileStatus@5f275ae4) (of class scala.Tuple2)
```

Code Here:

```
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
val A = Serialization.write(resultsMap)
println(A)
```

Now if I do a foreach:

```
 resultsMap.foreach(x => println(Serialization.write(x)))
```

I get some results back but they do not look correct:

```
{"_1":23,"_2":{}}
{"_1":32,"_2":{}}
```

The Tuples are missing their core information. I am assuming because the custom class we are using causing some sort of issues? Is there any way around it?

If I were to pull the second element of the map and convert it to JSON it would look like this:

```
{"errorCode":null,"id":null,"fieldType":"STRING","fieldIndex":0,"datasetFieldName":"RECORD_ID","datasetFieldSum":0.0,"datasetFieldMin":0.0,"datasetFieldMax":0.0,"datasetFieldMean":0.0,"datasetFieldSigma":0.0,"datasetFieldNullCount":0.0,"datasetFieldObsCount":0.0,"datasetFieldKurtosis":0.0,"datasetFieldSkewness":0.0,"frequencyDistribution":"(D,4488)","runStatusId":null,"lakeHdfsPath":"/user/jvy234/20140817_011500_zoot_kohls_offer_init.dat"}
```

Also on a side note the class was written in java, if that may be the culprit?

Full Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: (0,com.xxx.dts.dq.common.utils.DQOpsStoreProfileStatus@315a29f4) (of class scala.Tuple2)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.internalDecomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:132)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.decomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:67)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.decompose(Extraction.scala:194)
    at org.json4s.jackson.Serialization$.write(Serialization.scala:22)
    at com.xxx.dts.toolset.jsonWrite$.jsonClob(jsonWrite.scala:16)
    at com.xxx.dts.dq.profiling.DQProfilingEngine.profile(DQProfilingEngine.scala:255)
    at com.xxx.dts.dq.profiling.Profiler$.main(DQProfilingEngine.scala:64)
    at com.xxx.dts.dq.profiling.Profiler.main(DQProfilingEngine.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: You should see a stack trace after the error, always include it in posts like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have only two ways:

1. write your serialization for tuple2

   or
2. convert it to list maps, for example: `resultsMap.map(Map(_)).foreach(...)`

**Update:**
for serialization you can use something like this:

```
class Tuple2Serializer extends CustomSerializer[(String, Int)](   format => (
    {
      case JObject(JField(k, JInt(v))) => (k, v)
    },
    {
      case (s: String, t: Int) => (s -> t)
    }   ) )

implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats + new Tuple2Serializer
```